# How to automatically indent code in VS2008?

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2008, visual-c++, indentation, visual-studio-2008-sp1

How to automatically indent code in VS2008 ?

Somehow VS2008 seems very much non-programmer friendly compared to VS2005. 
I want to indent my source code (VC++) in VS2008. Can anyone kindly let me know how to do this in VS2008 ?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: In my VS2008 code is being indented. Expand your question by explaining in detail what you are doing, what you expect to be happening, and what is actually happening.

Answer (score 5):

<kbd>Ctrl</kbd> <kbd>K</kbd>, <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> <kbd>D</kbd> formats the whole document

<kbd>Ctrl</kbd> <kbd>K</kbd>, <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> <kbd>F</kbd> formats your selection